# Send multiple PHP variables to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to send multiple php variables to javascript function and I don't know how to achieve that. Any suggestions?

HTML code:

```
 <button class="btn btn-icon" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit-category" data-toggle="tooltip" 
 onClick=(setSelectedCategoryId2({{$category->id}},{{ $category->name }})) >
    <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span>
 </button>
```

Javascript function:

```
function setSelectedCategoryId2(id,name){
   alert(id, name)
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan $category->id $category->name inside html code

Comment: What error does this currently produce?

Comment: @Msencenb Uncaught ReferenceError: Product is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Product is the category name that i'm sending as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this? Data-attributes are recommended over inline event handlers

```js
document.querySelector("[data-toggle=modal]").addEventListener("click",function() {
  console.log(this.dataset.cat,this.dataset.name)
})
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-icon" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-edit-category" data-toggle="tooltip" 
data-cat="<?= $category->id ?>" data-name="<?= $category->name ?>">
    <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span>
 </button>
```

Comment: I think as a matter of best practice, we should see some encoding here.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code needs to be placed in a PHP file, then

```
onClick=(setSelectedCategoryId2({{$category->id}},{{ $category->name }}))
```

becomes

```
onClick="setSelectedCategoryId2('<?php echo $category->id; ?>','<?php echo $category->name; ?>')"
```

Avoid using ' in your php vars and that's done :)

Comment: This will break if the php variable's text contains a single or double quote.